# IE overflow hidden translate mouse over bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transform, mouseover, hidden

A rotated div with overflow hidden, with other internal rotated div with mouse on the hidden part of the inner div, the internet explore detects that the mouse is over the inner div, even with hidden content for another div. This is an IE bug? What better way to solve?

Internet explorer 11 in the code below, to hover over the red box, mouse over on the blue box is also applied. Is it a bug?

```css
div { width: 100px; height: 100px; opacity: 0.5; }
#div_1{ background: #f00; }
#div_2{ background: #0f0; transform: rotate(45deg); overflow: hidden; }
#div_3{ background: #00f; transform: rotate(-45deg); }
#div_1:hover{ opacity: 1; }
#div_2:hover{ opacity: 1; }
#div_3:hover{ opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div id="div_1">
    <div id="div_2">
     <div id="div_3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a bug it seems. However, html and are not yet made to do exotic things like this. If you could explain what you're trying to do, I could show you different ways to reach your goal.

Comment: Hello, David.

I would like to improve this site: http://www.martin.arq.br/#projetos
and others like this. In this case I used a 'workaround', but I was not happy.
Could use SVG or Canvas, but lose the semantics.
If you have any suggestions, I thank you.

All the best.